# Simple-but-not-too-simple drawing/image editing program

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, image-editor, vector-graphics

For years now I have retained an old copy of Jasc Paint Shop Pro 6 because I haven't been able to find any other software that provides the combination of simplicity and power that it has.  Part of it may just be because I'm used to it, but I don't think that's the only issue.  I'm looking for a replacement, mostly because I'm not confident in my ability to keep PSP 6 running indefinitely.

Ideally I'd like something open source, although free-as-in-no-money would be okay.  It needs to run on at least Windows and Linux.

Some features that are important to me:

- Ability to create and interleave both raster and vector layers.  PSP 6 has this and few other entry-level programs seem to.
- Simple and coherent interface.  I don't need 10,000 special "filters" and textures.  In PSP, there is a "tool options" window that has about half a dozen options for each drawing tool.  That is about the right level of complexity for me.  I don't want lots of sub-menus and whatnot to do simple stuff like change brush size.
- Solid range of drawing.  Again, I don't need super fancy stuff.  Flood fill, spray, lines, curves, presets for simple shapes like circles and stars, etc.  The ability to edit nodes for vector shapes is important.
- Basic image-manipulation effects.  At minimum, ability to flip/rotate selections.  Align/distribute tools that let you line up tops of objects, etc., are useful.  Stuff like blur, wave, pixelate, etc. are nice.
- Relatively lightweight.  Doesn't take 10 seconds to start up.
- Looks like an old-fashioned app.  This isn't so critical if the interface is good overall, but I have a distaste for image-editing apps whose UI consists of just a constellation of free-floating "palettes".

Basically I am looking for something that is easy enough to use without spending a lot of time learning its intricacies, but has enough of the main tools to be useful for everyday tasks like making a diagram from bits and pieces of different images.  This means the ability to easily select parts of images, cut and paste them, rotate and flip them, combine them with vector drawings for things like arrows and circles.  Another type of task would be adjusting colors and applying simple effects to modify images for various uses (e.g., adding color tints, simple airbrushing of blemishes, etc.).  It doesn't need to be "professional" (i.e., it's fine if my image edits aren't convincing "photoshops").  I'm looking for the 80/20 solution that gives 80% of the functionality with 20% of the learning time.

Comment: What are your requirements with respect to handling of text? Embedding fonts and typographic features, ease-of-use, support for Math equations, accuracy over prettiness....? I think in this respect many tools differ.

Comment: @knb: I don't need super great typography.  I want to be able to easily insert text boxes, and if I do it with vector text it should be editable.  Text should wrap to the dimensions of a box I set, etc.  Would be good to be able to to "text along curve" type of stuff.  Things like math equations aren't so essential but would be nice.

Comment: Krita seems to more or less fit the bill except that it is a full featured painting app, so it may have overkill features in most areas

Comment: I was a PSP 7 user for a long time, too. But on Win 10 it did not work anymore. I've switched to GIMP which might be to blown up for your purposes. For Windows I can recommend Paint.NET but it might be lacking some features you request. But it's pretty light weight IMO so you might give it a try. Alternatively Inkscape might fit but it's actually a Vector Image editing program which can handle pixel data in some extent, too.

Comment: I was about to ask the very same question. PSP was great in balance of easyness and power. I find that `gimp` is "too complex" for doing something like "open + do this + do that + save". When you save it starts asking a super-mega-complex thing about PNGs and so... An PicPick for example is too simple. I've see this has been asked half a year ago and no answers. Do you have any news on that? Did you find anything useful?

Comment: My smaller daughter used to use Krita (free) and Paint Tool Sai (for which I bought a license). But she used with a gfx tablet but IDK if any of those would be easy to use with mouse (which is what I use).

Comment: I don't know if they fit all your requirements, but I'd suggest checking out kolourpaint and inkscape.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx: Kolourpaint is raster-only and Inkscape is vector-only, so no, they don't fit my requirements.

Comment: @XaviMontero: I haven't found any really great answer.  Krita seems like maybe the closest but it is more complex than I'd like.